# Good automated system testing framework in perl for Android Mobile

Tags: perl

**OS : Android**

I am looking for good End to End testing framework under perl, where the tests can be written in perl and managed in a comfortable way.

Answer (score 2):

As much I as love Perl, I would not recommend doing that.

Instead, you should stick to native Android testing framework, which is JUnit with few Android extensions. It is very well documented and perfectly supported to run on device using Android instrumentation framework (`am instrument ...`).

Doing it any other way is simply asking for trouble. Reasons are many, but probably most important one is that Android does not support running any scripting languages (Perl, Python, etc) natively. Well, there is [SL4A framework](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) that should to be able to run Python, Perl, Lua, etc, but it is still very much alpha quality software and using it requires way too much to be usable without pain.

Comment: But what if, i do not know Java :( I only know Perl :)